# How to move special folders (Users, Program Data, etc) to a different drive on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, special-locations

I have a small SSD drive `C:` for OS stuff, and a larger hybrid HDD (two disks with mirroring, for improved reliability) `D:` for the data.

I'd like to move special Windows directories, specifically `C:\Users\` and `C:\Program Data\` to drive `D:`, to improve reliability of my user data, and to reduce the space occupied by program data on my `C:` drive.
I can't find a good answer to it. Most answers say I can just use a link junction, but I don't trust this approach. Something tells me that Windows Update/Upgrade may wreck it in the future if I go along with that approach.

Has anyone successfully managed to move special folders to another drive?
What would be the best approach to accomplish that?

Comment: You can move Documents, Pictures, Videos and like. But do not move AppData and those folders as that can damage Windows. Program Data does not want to move on my machine. Best solution: Much larger C: Drive

Comment: @John The solution proposed in the duplicate should work fine. It's the same as having /home as a separated partition in Linux.